# extract certain substring

Tags: text-processing, cut, bioinformatics

I have a file like this:

```
RSID1 RSID2
chr1_169894240_G_T_b38  chr1_169894240_G_T_b38
chr1_169894240_G_T_b38  chr1_169891332_G_A_b38
chr1_169891332_G_A_b38  chr1_169891332_G_A_b38
chr1_169661963_G_A_b38  chr1_169661963_G_A_b38
chr1_169661963_G_A_b38  chr1_169697456_A_T_b38
chr1_169697456_A_T_b38  chr1_169697456_A_T_b38
chr1_27636786_T_C_b38   chr1_27636786_T_C_b38
chr1_196651787_C_T_b38  chr1_196651787_C_T_b38
chr6_143501715_T_C_b38  chr6_143501715_T_C_b38
```

I want to extract info just like: `chr1_169894240 chr1_169894240`. I don't want to have other info. I just want `chr_pos` I am confuse how to extract this info because the length is varying. In one case its 9 length and in other its 10. So if i use `cut` command for some its showing write value like `chr_pos` but for some its showing `chr_pos_` Can anyone please help me out with this.

Comment: Do you want a list of the results one per line, or do you want a list of _pairs_ of results two per line?

Comment: I want one per line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk 'NR >1 {split($1, array, "_"); print array[1] "_" array[2]; split($2, array, "_"); print array[1] "_" array[2]}' FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU `grep` you can pick out a matching pattern, displaying one per line, like this

```
grep -oE '\<chr[[:digit:]]+_[[:digit:]]+' file
```

The regular expression can be broken down like this

- `\<` - match against the beginning of a word
- `chr` - literal characters
- `[[:digit:]]+` - one or more (the `+`) digits
- `_` - literal underscore

Answer (score 0):

You can't really use `cut` here as you would need to use both banks and `_` as delimiter to pick out the fields that you need, and `cut` only supports single character delimiters.

Using `awk` instead:

```bsh
awk -F '[[:blank:]_]+' 'NR > 1 { $0 = sprintf("%s_%d %s_%d", $1, $2, $6, $7) }; 1' file
```

This treats the input as lines containing fields delimited by blanks or underscores.  The header on line one is passed through unchanged, but the other lines are rewritten using the 1st, 2nd, 6th, and 7th blank-or-underscore-delimited field.

---

You *could* use `cut`, but it would be a bit messy, and you'd lose the header:

```bsh
tail -n +2 file | tr -s '[:blank:]_' '[\t*]' | cut -f 1,2,6,7 | tr '\t' '\n' | paste -d '_ ' - - - -
```

This strips the first line from the input using `tail`, then converts all blanks and underscores to tabs (removing consecutive tabs from the result), cuts out the wanted columns, transforms the columns to separate lines with that second `tr`, then uses `paste` to reconstruct the data for the final result.